# Toggle menu is not fully visible on click event

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have to create toggle menu with items, when user clicks on the button. But that menu is not fully visible.

In html, I define toggle button with menu as that:

```
<div class="button toggle">Toggle on right
    <div class="toggle-menu">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a><br />
        <a href="#">Link 2</a><br />
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS (SCSS) for it:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    background-color: lime;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &.toggle > .toggle-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        right: 0;
        background-color: lime;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/sh7xmpk3/), where is my whole code.

**PS:** *This is not my actual code on live page. Just as example, but same problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply z-index:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    background-color: lime;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &.toggle > .toggle-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        right: 0;
        background-color: lime;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 99; /* added here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works on this example, but not in live code (reason: I already have z-indexes on elements), so I will update question asap.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I will try to make better duplicate, my actual code on website is too long to post it here or jsfiddle (idk where is that bug).

Comment: I will try as much as I can, but I cannot show you whole code, it is commercial and company issue.

Comment: @debute : replicate the issue or share the code where you facing the issue. According to the question it's answered.

Comment: I wil try to do it myself, I copied every style from website to jsfiddle, still working just on jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is updated version with duplicated code from my project http://jsfiddle.net/debute/sh7xmpk3/1/ (if you are still interested)